# can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock

Tags: mysql, installation, centos, rpm

I am trying install MySQL server rpm using **root user** in Cent OS 6.8 but getting below error message.

```
# rpm -iv MySQL-server-5.6.29-1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
warning: MySQL-server-5.6.29-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
warning: waiting for transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock
^Cerror: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Interrupted system call)
```

Could you please help on this.

Comment: Did you press `CTRL-C` while the process was running ? It seems that way... `Interrupted system call`...

Comment: Yes, He have pressed `CTRL-C`. Just remove the lock file and try again `\rm /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock`